# Searching for wildcard certificate in local store?

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

I have a routine that searches my cert store for a cert that matches the subject name... e.g., I have a cert with the subject of foobar.blah.com and my script does this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "foobar.blah.com"})
```

and this works as expected... i.e., finds the entry.

However, I'm trying to do this same process against an official wild card certificate, e.g., *.blah.com but attempts at using this same syntax is failing to work.

I've attempted to use other forms search options (-like, -contains, etc.) but nothing seems to be working.
Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-match` expects a regex pattern as its right-hand argument. In regex, `*` is a quantifier, meaning "0 or more". To match the literal character `*`, escape it with `\`:

```
{ $_.Subject -match '\*\.blah\.com'}
```

`.` is also a special character (matching any single character)

If you're ever in doubt over which characters to escape, use the `[regex]::Escape()` method:

```
$Pattern = [regex]::Escape('*.blah.com')
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match $Pattern}
```